# How to keep API key of restful webservices safe in android app?

Tags: android, rest, api, authentication, api-key

I have been doing an Android project involving restful web services. What is the best way to keep API key safe. I have read a lot online. Many say it is safe to keep key in the server and use it and that it will be safe. I don't understand what that means. By my understanding saving key in the server means that the app needs to fetch it during operation by using volley or any other httpclient by providing an url. The attacker can decompile the apk file and see the url from which the key is obtained, get the key and do his nasty work. Am I getting things wrong? How can storing API key in the server be safe? Please help me understand.

Comment: Use authHeaders with API

Comment: will authHeaders remove the threats imposed by reverse engineeering completely?

Answer (score 0):

you should write something like a SecureStorage using the Android Keystore and SharedPreferences and put the string inside it. We are currently developing such a library --> have a look at it [here](https://github.com/adorsys/secure-storage-android/tree/develop)